# REGULAR EXPRESSION (url.rewrite)

Tags: regex, linux

I want to use url rewrite for linux `lighttpd.conf` but I can't get the right regular expression.

My web url is  `ip/cgi/aaa/bbb` and I want to rewrite the url path. My target is `/var/www/cgi/aaa.cgi?par=bbb`

I write the rule as `"^/cgi/([^/]+)\/(.*)?"=> "/var/www/cgi/$1.cgi?par=$2"`
But somehow I can't get the parameter `par` value.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because of your anchoring at the beginning of the input.

```
^/cgi
```

..will not match `ip/cgi`, because `ip` is at the start.. not `/cgi`. To fix it.. put `ip` in front of what you have:

```
 ^ip/cgi/([^/]+)\/(.*)?
# ^^ this part
```

Below is the output once that change is made:

[image: Regex output]

Comment: but the ip is different , and how to i write the rule

Comment: Remove the anchor character `^`.. it will probably work after that.

Comment: but i use my rule "^/cgi/([^/]+)\/(.*)?"=> "/var/www/cgi/$1.cgi?par=$2" , and i can go to cgi but i can't get the par value

Comment: I remove ^ but the result is the same

Comment: I think ip is host , and the url is /cgi/aaa/bbb , so use ^/cgi/... can work.

Answer (score 0):

"^" matches at beginning of string. As your ip is dynamic, try to match from "cgi" as it is absolute.

I tried below input at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and worked fine.

```
/cgi/([^/]+)\/(.*)? 
/var/www/cgi/$1.cgi?par=$2
ip/cgi/aaa/bbb
```

result is ip/var/www/cgi/aaa.cgi?par=bbb

If you don't want "ip" in result string, use

```
(.*)/cgi/([^/]+)\/(.*)?
/var/www/cgi/$2.cgi?par=$3
ip/cgi/aaa/bbb
```

result is /var/www/cgi/aaa.cgi?par=bbb (without ip)